# Map selection in automatch CoH

Tags: company-of-heroes

The automatch setup screen will allow you to deselect a fixed number 3(?) maps from the ones included in the automatch rotation. I have noticed though that this seems to be more of a hint than anything else as I have regularly been given de-selected maps.

Does anyone know exactly what de-selecting a map is meant to do?

Comment: Maybe a bug, I've noticved sometimes when I change map selections, then the save the selection, the box listing the maps is empty unless I scroll up and down.  Gives me the impression they might not have put a high priority on that feature being tested.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question. This refers to the old RelicOnline hosted CoH, and not the new steam backed version.